# Jmeter - The Save Responses to a file creates a corrupted file

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and i have a http request that downloads a zip file.
I have added the `Save Responses to a file` listener to get that zip file and use in the body of another http request. However, that zip file is corrupted.
Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you download the zip file, is it corrupted ? Did you try to unzip it ? or the zip file which you try to use in another HTTP request becomes corrupted once you upload it ?

Comment: When i tried to unzip the downloaded file , i get an error message saying that it may be corrupted.

Comment: What happens if you download the file directly in a browser and unzip it ? instead of downloading it via JMeter.

Comment: I get a valid zip file.

Comment: Can you check what is the HTTP Request Method do you use ? You should use "GET" request. Its working perfectly for me

Comment: I am using a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [Save Response to a File](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener doesn't "corrupt" the files, I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. You don't really download zip file, check `${filename}` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) listener combination. If you see something like `20191209-1559_1.html` - most probably you hit some form of error page and JMeter saves a HTML file instead of ZIP file
2. The file itself is corrupt, i.e. you're downloading an incomplete zip file due to server issues
3. There are 4 errors related to your test execution, check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), most probably you will get some hints regarding what went wrong:

   [image]

Comment: In the debug sampler, the value of ${filename} is a zip file and there is no error in jmeter.log file.